# Auto read local file with html js or reactjs framework

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, local

I have researched for many hours to find the way to auto read local file with html and js , but the only way is create input tag in html but user need to select file in their computer and read it - this way doesn't auto read (I use http-server command to run html file).

I know direct access "file://" is blocked by browsers for security reasons or some solution like "--allow-file-access-from-files"

But when i use reactjs and read file from public folder, it's work (app create by npx create-react-app )

Could you tell me the difference between them and give a solution to auto read local txt file with only html,js.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

create-react-app is just serving your local files via [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/), it is the same as using Nginx to serve your local files or using Apache. When you create a build using webpack you are merely guiding your server to serve static content at a particular host.

You may want to refer to [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) and [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and read how they work.

Comment: Thank you for fast rely, what about http-server to run localhost:8080, does it serving my local file, and why I can't read my local txt file via html,js file.Can you explain it to me

Comment: It depends upon the loader, for example, you may very well ready your CSS and HTML just like that you will need a loader for your type, in your case your can use webpack's raw-loader https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/